# Show that if for $n \ge 1$, $(X_0, \ldots, X_n)$ has probability function $f_n$, then $X$ is a Markov Chain with transition matrix $\mathbb P$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $S$ a set of states and $\mathbb P=\{p_{i,j}\}_{i,j \in S}$ be a transition matrix.

I've proved that $f_n(i_0,\ldots,i_n) := f_0(i_0) p_{i_0 i_1} \dots p_{i_{n-1} i_n}, \ \ (i_0, \ldots, i_n) \in S^{n+1}$ is a probability function on $S^{n+1}$ given that $f_0(i_0), \ \ i_0 \in S$ is a probability function on $S$.

Let $X := (X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence of discrete stochastic variables with set of states $S$. Show that if for $n \ge 1$, $(X_0, \ldots, X_n)$ has probability function $f_n$, then $X$ is a Markov Chain with transition matrix $\mathbb P$.

Idea:

It is enough to show that for every $n \ge 1: P(X_n = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = p_{i_{n-1,n}}$ ?

But $f_n(i_0,\ldots,i_n) := f_0(i_0) p_{i_0 i_1} \dots p_{i_{n-1} i_n}, \ \ (i_0, \ldots, i_n) \in S^{n+1}$ does not reflect this property ?

Answer (score 1):

If $P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) \neq 0$,
\begin{align*}
P(X_n = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0)&=\frac{P(X_n = i_n , X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0)}{P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0)}\\
&= \frac{P(X_n = i_n , X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0)}{\sum_{i_n}P(X_n = i_n , X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0)}\\
& = \frac{f_n(i_0,\cdots, i_n)}{\sum_{i_n}f_n(i_0,\cdots, i_n)} \\
&= p_{i_{n-1}i_n} \text{ (we used that $(p_{ij})$ is a transition matrix )}
\end{align*}

Comment: Why is the last equality true ?

Comment: Because: \begin{align*}\sum_{i_n}f_n(i_0,\cdots, i_n) &=\sum_{i_n} f_0(i_0)p_{i_0i_1}\cdots p_{i_{n-1}i_n} \\&=f_0(i_0)p_{i_0i_1}\cdots p_{i_{n-2}i_{n-1}} \sum_{i_n} p_{i_{n-1}i_n}\\ & =f_0(i_0)p_{i_0i_1}\cdots p_{i_{n-2}i_{n-1}}\end{align*}

where we used $\sum_{i_n} p_{i_{n-1}i_n} = 1$.

Comment: What about "If $P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) \neq 0$ ? What if $P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = 0$ ? - Should we ignore this case, because our sequence of RV's cannot take on such values ? - The requirement $P(X_n = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = p_{i_{n-1}i_n}$ should not be met if $P(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) =0$ ??

Comment: In my book $$P(X_n = i_n \mid X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}, \ldots, X_0 = i_0) = p_{i_{n-1,n}}$$ must be true for every $(i_0, \ldots, i_n) \in S^{n+1}$ ?